# pycurl error: ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

Tags: python, odoo

I want to integrate PayTR payment gateway with odoo10. I followed the PayTR's developers guide and found a sample codes php script in it. After converting php script to python script, I am getting the error:

> ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

Here are the logs:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwRCX.png)

Below is the piece of code:

```
@http.route('/my/payment', type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def pay_now(self, **kw):

    partner            = request.env.user.partner_id
    res                = request.env['account.payment'].sudo().search([('partner_id' ,  '=',  partner.id)])
    print res
    acquirer           = request.env['payment.acquirer'].sudo().search([('provider', '=', 'paytr')])
    merchant_id        = acquirer.paytr_seller_account
    merchant_key       = acquirer.paytr_merchant_key
    merchant_salt      = acquirer.paytr_merchant_salt
    email              = acquirer.paytr_email_account
    payment_amount     = 300    #example
    merchant_oid       = "50"     #example
    merchant_ok_url    = "http://www.example.com/success.php"
    merchant_fail_url  = "http://www.example.com/error.php"
    user_basket        = "sample product" #example 
    user_basket        = base64.b64encode(bytes(user_basket).encode('utf-8'))
    user_ip            = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
    print user_ip
    timeout_limit      = "30"
    debug_on           = 1
    test_mode          = 0
    no_installment     = 0
    max_installment    = 0
    currency           = "TL"
    hash_str           = str(merchant_id) + str(user_ip) + str(merchant_oid) + str(email) + str(payment_amount) + str(user_basket) + str(no_installment) + str(max_installment) + str(currency) + str(test_mode)
    print hash_str
    str_salt           = hash_str + str(merchant_salt)
    print str_salt
    message            = bytes(str_salt).encode('utf-8')
    secret             = bytes(merchant_key).encode('utf-8')

    # paytr_token        = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(str(merchant_key), str_salt, digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest())
    paytr_token        = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest())
    print paytr_token
    values = {
    'merchant_id'       : merchant_id,
    'user_ip'           : user_ip       ,
    'merchant_oid'      : merchant_oid  ,
    'email'             : str(email)         ,
    'payment_amount'    : int(payment_amount)     ,
    'currency'          : str(currency)      ,
    'user_basket'       : user_basket,
    'no_installment'    : no_installment,
    'max_installment'   : max_installment,
    'paytr_token'       : paytr_token,
    'user_name'         : str(partner.name),
    'user_address'      : str(partner.street),
    'user_phone'        : str(partner.phone),
    'merchant_ok_url'   : str(merchant_ok_url),
    'merchant_fail_url' : str(merchant_fail_url),
    'test_mode'         : test_mode,
    'debug_on'          : int(debug_on),
    'timeout_limit'     : int(timeout_limit),
    'lang'              : "en", 
    }

    print values
    post_data = urlencode(values) 
    print "postfields : " +post_data
    buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
    buff = StringIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://www.paytr.com/odeme/api/get-token')
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, post_data) 
    c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buff)
    resp_data = c.perform()
    print('Status: %d' % c.getinfo(c.RESPONSE_CODE))
    print('Status: %f' % c.getinfo(c.TOTAL_TIME))
    c.close()
    data = buff.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
    buff.close()
    resp_data = json.load(resp_data)
    if resp_data['status'] =='success':
        token = resp_data['token']
    else :
        print resp_data['reason']
    template = 'retailer_payment.pay_now'
    return request.render(template, token)
```

With this, ***result*** contains nothing and throws:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Can someone help me to understand what's wrong here?

Comment: Can some one help me here?